# how to insert scroll button on drop down in php html

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, scroll

I want scroll button after i click on the *Select your country* textbox anyone know how to insert scroll button. Here my code :

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <label for='formCountry'>Select your country of residence</label><br>
    <select name="formCountry">
        <option value="">Select a country...</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what did you want to scroll ??

Comment: Hey if your dropdown has large ammount of option than it's automatic add scroll down option

Comment: I want to be able to scroll the option list.

Comment: yes plz check my ans if you fix the height of dropdown than

Comment: @Parth Chavda. I didn't know it will automatically add a scroll down option. Thank you very much. May God bless you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's automatic take scorll button in dropdown but if you still limit the showing option,than use below code :

apply height and overflow in css:

**CSS:**

```
.select{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
   <select name="formCountry" class="select">
        <option value="">Select a country...</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you @Parth Chavda. :)